# Get index of clicked element in collection with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-selectors

How do I get the index of clicked item in the code below?

```
$('selector').click(function (event) {
    // get index in collection of the clicked item ...
});
```

With Firebug I saw this: `jQuery151017197709735298827: 2` (I've clicked in the second element).

Answer (score 126):

This will alert the index of the clicked selector (starting with 0 for the first):

```
$('selector').click(function(){
    alert( $('selector').index(this) );
});
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! It is best solution to get the right index depends of parent element.

Comment: yeah this way if we didn't have a reference to 'this' but just knew the element by a class that was added we could use this approach

Comment: First I thought `selector` was redundant, but if there is other elements (accessible via other selectors) within the same parent, this gets it right

Comment: [Official docs for index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

Answer (score 67):

```
$('selector').click(function (event) {
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bCTAh/)

Comment: This caused me some issues. Incorrect index being returned. @Ant's solution worked for me though.

Comment: Sorry this answer is (quite frequently) wrong. it returns the index of the clicked element *within its direct parent*, so if a some buttons are selected, and each one is wrapped in its own div, then the index will always be 0

Answer (score 32):

### Siblings

`$(this).index()` can be used to get the index of the clicked element if the elements are siblings.

```
<div id="container">
    <a href="#" class="link">1</a>
    <a href="#" class="link">2</a>
    <a href="#" class="link">3</a>
    <a href="#" class="link">4</a>
</div>
```

```js
$('#container').on('click', 'a', function() {
  console.log($(this).index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <a href="#" class="link">1</a>
  <a href="#" class="link">2</a>
  <a href="#" class="link">3</a>
  <a href="#" class="link">4</a>
</div>
```

---

### Not siblings

> If no argument is passed to the `.index()` method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object **relative to its sibling elements**.

Pass the selector to the [`index(selector)`](https://api.jquery.com/index/#index-selector).

```
$(this).index(selector);
```

**Example:**

Find the index of the `<a>` element that is clicked.

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="#" class="adwa">0001</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="#" class="adwa">0002</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="#" class="adwa">0003</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="#" class="adwa">0004</a></td>
</tr>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ktg22seu/1/)

```js
$('#table').on('click', '.adwa', function() {
    console.log($(this).index(".adwa"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>vendor id</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#" class="adwa">0001</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#" class="adwa">0002</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#" class="adwa">0003</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#" class="adwa">0004</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ahhh, the "Not siblings" was the one I was looking for!

Answer (score 11):

Just do this way:-

```
$('ul li').on('click', function(e) {
    alert($(this).index()); 
});
```

**OR**

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

check this out
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/get-index-of-same-class-element-on-click
then
http://jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/d6rFM/2/

```
var index = $('selector').index(this);
console.log(index)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using .bind(this), try this:

`let index = Array.from(evt.target.parentElement.children).indexOf(evt.target);`

```
$(this.pagination).find("a").on('click', function(evt) {
        let index = Array.from(evt.target.parentElement.children).indexOf(evt.target);

        this.goTo(index);
    }.bind(this))
```